# Make a camel-case function using a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am brand new to Javascript and trying to figure out how to camel-case any string by using a for loop. This is what I have so far.

```
function camelCase(str) {
 var splitStr = "";
 var result = "";

 splitStr = str.split(" ");
 for(var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++){
 result += splitStr[i][0].toUpperCase() + 
   splitStr[i].slice(1);
  }
  return result;
 }

console.log(camelCase("hello there people"));
```

it returns "HelloTherePeople" - How do you I make the very first index of splitStr (splitStr[0][0]) be excluded from toUpperCase, but still included in the beginning of the string?

Comment: that doesn't "camel-case any string" even if it worked. Only strings with spaces

Comment: you will need a dictionary if you want to CamelCase without spaces!

Comment: You do the conversion, then turn the first character back to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

What is your delimiter? This method assumes an underscore `_`. Change it to a space if you want a space. Or make it a variable you can pass to camelize.

```
if( !String.prototype.camelize )
    String.prototype.camelize = function(){
        return this.replace(/_+(.)?/g, function(match, chr) {
            return chr ? chr.toUpperCase() : '';
        });
    }

"a_new_string".camelize()
//"aNewString"
```

The regex `/_+(.)?/g/` says find 1 or more `_` characters followed by any character `.`, the `(.)` creates a capturing group, so you are able to get that one character. It's passed to the function as the second paramater `chr`.  The `?` means not greedy so it will stop at the next `_`. The `g` means globally, pretty much means find all matches.

`String.prototype.replace` [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

change return like this:

```
return result[0].toLowerCase()+result.substr(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check inside the loop to see if you are on the first index.

```js
function camelCase(str) {
  //splitStr will be an array
  var splitStr = [];
  var result = "";
  
  splitStr = str.split(" ");
  
  //Capitalize first letter of words starting from the second one
  for(var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++){
  
    //first word
    if (i===0) {
      //Good practice to lowercase the first letter regardless of input
      result += splitStr[i][0].toLowerCase() + splitStr[i].slice(1);
    }
  
    else {
      //rest can proceed as before
      result += splitStr[i][0].toUpperCase() + 
      splitStr[i].slice(1);    
    }

  }
  
  
  return result;
  }

console.log(camelCase("hello there people"));
```

Alternatively, the loop can even start on the second index. However, you will have to check if the length of `splitStr` before running a loop from the second index